# Battery upgrade for HP 15-BS laptop

Tags: laptop, battery-life, battery

I am using an HP Laptop `15-BS` series for the last 4 years. For the past few days, I have been experiencing that the laptop's battery is not providing enough backup.

Below are the specs of this battery

1. 2670mah
2. 14.6 vdc
3. Model num HSTNN-LB7W
4. JC04 4 cells battery

It looks like this

[image]

**Problem**:

- That it is always unavailable on the HP store.
- I want to upgrade my battery that has a longer life, better backup.

**So is it possible that I can use HS04 or KI04 models instead of JC04? If I do so will that be an upgrade?**

Answer (score 1):

Don't risk incompatible batteries. Prefer buying it from a third-party shop than getting a different model.

If you think that is not an upgrade, batteries degrade over time, so if you are using it for a few years already, a new battery will be an upgrade